# Checking disjointness between subsets of a poset

Tags: lattices

If there is a poset $(P, \le)$ and two sets $X \subseteq P$ and $Y \subseteq P$, and we have a way $f : P^2 \to 2$ to efficiently compute for any $(x, y) \in P^2$ whether there exists a $z \in P$ such that $(x \le z) \wedge (y \le z)$, we want to return $\mathbf{T}$ if there exists a pair $(x, y) \in X \times Y$ such that $f(x, y) = 1$ and $\mathbf{F}$ otherwise, using the fewest possible number of calls to $f$ and $\le$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further information, you can't do any better than $O(n^2)$ queries to $f$, where $n=|X|+|Y|$.  There is a simple adversary argument.

Imagine you have an algorithm that uses $o(n^2)$ queries.  Consider running it on a set $X,Y$ chosen so that $f(x,y)=0$ for all $x \in X, y \in Y$.  If the algorithm is correct, the algorithm must return F on this input.  Since the algorithm runs in $o(n^2)$ time, there must exist some pair of elements $x_0,y_0$ that was never queried.  Now run the algorithm on a pair of sets $X,Y$ chosen so that $f(x_0,y_0)=1$ but $f(x,y)=0$ for all other pairs $x,y$.  We see that $f$ always returns 0 during this execution, too, so this execution must follow exactly the same path as the first execution, and thus must also return F on this input.  However, returning F on this input is incorrect.  Therefore, there is no algorithm that takes $o(n^2)$ time and is always correct.

Comment: I don't understand why the execution of f on the second X, Y must follow the same path as the first X, Y. That seems to presuppose that all the elements of X and Y are completely indistinguishable, when in reality X and Y are already equipped with poset structure.

Comment: I meant the execution of the algorithm, not of f.

Comment: I modified the question to make it clear that $\le$ is also a valid query.

Comment: Though I guess you could always implement $x \le y$ as $f(x, y) \stackrel{?}{=} y$.

Comment: @taktoa, I am choosing inputs that are the worst case, so I have chosen them so that they are indistinguishable.  Note that there exists a poset that is consistent with the two inputs I suggest.  Allowing $\le$ queries does not change the result I list here.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. What about an output sensitive algorithm? Or we could parameterize on something, like for example the sparsity of the $\le$ relation.

Comment: @taktoa, Many things are possible.  I suggest spending some time thinking about your application domain and what makes sense for it, and seeing what the best algorithm you can find is for that domain.